# Does keep Win32::GetANSIPathName unicode if supported?

Tags: perl, winapi, unicode, character-encoding, filenames

Does `Win32::GetANSIPathName(FILENAME)` from [Win32](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32) keep the full Unicode name if supported by the Win32 OS?

Comment: Could you give an example? It's not clear what you mean. (It doesn't have to be code.)

Comment: @ikegami: I tried to download a video with an Arabic name. In the console output the name looks like `?????_????`. When I try to `open` a file with such a name I get an "Invalid argument" error message. So I thought maybe `Win32::GetANSIPathName()` could handle this - without exactly knowing what `Win32::GetANSIPathName()` is for. But this has been settled now because it didn't solve the problem. (And I don't know what short and long name means in this context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

However, even if the OS does support the Unicode filename, this'll return "the short name if the long name cannot be represented in the system codepage."  As noted in the link, it'll always be ANSI (non-Unicode).

Comment: What does it do if there isn't a short name?

Comment: Everything has an 8.3 filename representation on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong around around. `Win32::GetANSIPathName()` is what would give you `?????_????` from the Arabic name.

The information has already been lost when you get `?????_????`. You'd need to start with the real name.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I used `GetANSIPathName()` this way: `use utf8; use Win32; my $file = 'Arabic_name'; $file = Win32::GetANSIPathName($file); open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;` Initially I  thought maybe `GetANSIPathName()` would work like `Text::Unidecode`.

Comment: Then your last comment was useless and was misleading. When asked to give an example of what you wanted from `GetANSIPathName`, you said you had file name that looks like `?????_????`.